# share computer sound on skype?

Tags: sound, skype

I would like to be able to play an audio file from my computer so that the person on another end will hear it via Skype. I don't want to use the computer's microphone because as soon as I switch to it and play something back, there's a terrible feedback. Could anyone point me in the right direction? My sound preferences have SB Audigy as hardware and input, but the person on the other end cannot hear anything from my computer audio. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Screen sharing with system sounds is only available using UWP - Skype for Windows 10.

Answer (score 4):

First make sure you have `paprefs` and `pavucontrol` installed.

In `paprefs`, go to the Simultaneous Output tab and check the box here.  This will allow both you and Skype to hear the computer sounds.

Go into `pavucontrol` when connected to skype.  Go to the playback tab.  Play the sound you want to play, and the application will appear here.  Change its playback setting to the simultaneous output.

Go to the recording tab and when you want to send a sound effect, change it to record from the Monitor of an audio device that Skype is NOT currently playing to (and not Simultaneous).  If you have no other devices, you can create a virtual one with `modprobe snd-dummy`

You will have to switch the skype input back to mic to talk and there isn't a direct way to record from both the mic and the snd-dummy.  However you could run another application that would take your mic and output that to the snd-dummy channel like `sox -d -d echo 0.8 0.88 1 0.4` which you could even use to change the pitch of your voice.

Make sure skype is not sending its output to Simultaneous or the channel you are recording from or it will generate feedback.  This can be troublesome if you are using a browser to do both generate sounds and record sounds.  In that case I usually have to open 2 different browsers to get the sound to not echo.