# How can I share computer audio on Skype

Tags: sound, skype, sharing

I would like to be able to share my computer sound on Skype. This option seems not to be available in Skype for Linux, but I understand (from an answer I read on this forum - "Share computer sound on Skype?") that there is a workaround involving paprefs and pavucontrol. I have successfully installed them both, and have ticked the "Simultaneous output" box in paprefs, but I don't really understand how to proceed from here. All I need is for the other person to be able to hear me as well as the audio that is playing on my computer when I share my screen. Thanks a lot for any help anybody can offer.
p.s., my system is Ubuntu MATE (18.04.4 LTS Mate 1.20.1) and I'm running the latest version of Skype (8.61.0.95)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a fake device, push audio to it, and have Skype use this as your microphone.

```bsh
# Determine "Computer Audio" Sink
pacmd list-sinks | egrep '^\s+name:'
    name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-surround-21

# Determine "Microphone" Source
pacmd list-sources | egrep '^\s+name:'
    name: alsa_input.usb-Blue_Microphones_Yeti_Stereo_Microphone_X-00.analog-stereo

# Create Fake Microphone for Skype
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name="FakeMicrophone" sink_properties=device.description="FakeMicrophone"
# Tie "Microphone" to FakeMicrophone
pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1 source=alsa_input.usb-Blue_Microphones_Yeti_Stereo_Microphone_X-00.analog-stereo sink=FakeMicrophone
# Tie "Computer Audio" Monitor to FakeMicrophone
pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1 source=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-surround-21.monitor sink=FakeMicrophone
```

While `FakeMicrophone` is a sink (output), it has a Monitor `FakeMicrophone.monitor`, which is a source (input).  For this same reason, "Computer Audio" has `.monitor` in the above commands.

If you use `pavucontrol`, you can see this show up and make adjustments as needed.  You can even adjust which sources map to the new sink.

Once you figure out the required commands, you can have this persist by adding them to `/etc/pulse/default.pa` (bottom is fine), and dropping the `pactl` part:

```
# Create Fake Microphone for Skype
load-module module-null-sink sink_name="FakeMicrophoneSink" sink_properties=device.description="FakeMicrophoneSink"
# Tie "Microphone" to FakeMicrophoneSink
load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1 source=alsa_input.usb-Blue_Microphones_Yeti_Stereo_Microphone_X-00.analog-stereo sink=FakeMicrophoneSink
# Tie "Computer Audio" Monitor to FakeMicrophoneSink
load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1 source=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-surround-21.monitor sink=FakeMicrophoneSink
```

---

When launching applications from the command line, you can adjust which audio output they will use by setting `PULSE_SINK`:

```
PULSE_SINK="WhateverSink" mpv /path/to/video
```

```
export PULSE_SINK="WhateverSink"
mpv /path/to/video
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this very detailed answer. I understand that these commands go straight into Terminal. But before I start, I'd just like to ask you this: I am not very experienced with the inner workings of Linux, and cannot afford to mess up my audio. Should anything go wrong with the procedure, is there a risk that I might?

Comment: A restart of the system, or `pulseaudio`, would revert any commands you run.  That's why you run the commands, figure out what works, and then add them to the config.  The biggest risk is when you add them to the config, but you can always just remove them again and restart the system.

Comment: Thank you again, earthmeLon. I am not sure exactly what happened, but in the end the problem somehow fixed itself: between my last message to you and this one, I played around with my pavucontrol settings and somehow I managed to fix the problem. Unfortunately, I mucked there for such a long time that I don't really know what I did right :|

Comment: I can confirm that this WORKS!!!! THANKS!!!!!

Comment: the only problem is that when I plug and unplug the earbuds, I hear very annoying echoes. To fix you have to unload the modules with "pactl unload-module module-null-sink" and "pactl unload-module module-loopback" and redo the procedure. I have created a simple bash script that simply do the commands automatically so that I don't even have to entry them by myself.

Comment: In each scenario I've been in, I've either been able to turn off my speakers, or mute that channel on the main audio output.  You can create a fake Sink (ie: "SkypeSink"), push audio to that, and monitor the "SkypeSink" on your "FakeMicrophone" and isolate the audio in that way.  If you hear yourself, it's because `# Tie "Microphone" to FakeMicrophone` pushes audio to a device you are actively listening to and should instead just push it to whatever sink Skype uses by iteself.

Comment: thanks @earthmeLon but I think I'll settle for it. btw, If you have "FakeMicrophone" that does not seem to be active or working, try entering this in a terminal:
`pacmd set-sink-mute FakeMicrophone off`

Comment: @earthmeLon sorry if I bother you, but I'm trying to do this but with the bluetooth audio instead of internal computer audio... so I put the bleutooth card name bluez_sink.00_18_09_76_AE_5F.a2dp_sink.monitor instead of the previous alsa output pci... but FakeMicrophone can only "hear" the microphone, not the audio of the bluetooth headphones... why doesn't it work according to you?

Comment: anyway, actually, you can just use pipewire and will have 0 issues. follow this guide: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/lfxbik/tutorial_how_to_share_audio_on_discord_or_any/

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to use two devices, say for example a laptop and a phone along with two Microsoft accounts. One can directly use `pavucontrol` to connect sound output to mic input.

With this method there's no need for any additional scripts or shell commands.

In my case I also used one set of headphones for the laptop, and one set of headphones for the phone.

(Note: I'm actually using Debian 12 (bookworm), but I think it could work fine on Debian derived distributions like Ubuntu as well)

According to Microsoft it's alright for one person to have two accounts:

https://www.bing.com/search?q=is+it+okay+to+have+two+microsoft+accounts

On the phone one can be logged in with one's main Skype account, and then on the laptop which is running Linux one can log in with an extra Skype account that's used to send sound out (could also optionally share screen at the same time).

One can create a test call between the two accounts (the extra account on the laptop, and the main account logged in with the phone).

Then one can use this solution which involves using `pavucontrol` for connecting sound output to mic input:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82259/how-to-pipe-audio-output-to-mic-input

In `pavucontrol` in the Recording tab I just set Skype: Input from to "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo".

[Image for `pavucontrol` settings for sharing sound in Skype for Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srvbq.png)

Then on the phone I could hear the music playing through the Skype connection.

I plugged in headphones to the laptop, and also headphones to the phone.

One could of course add additional people to the call, and they would also be getting the audio from the account that's logged in on the laptop.

There seemed to be a bit of a decrease in quality inasmuch as perhaps Skype isn't really designed for sending very high quality audio over the regular microphone connection.

Sound sharing for something like a music video is better in Windows, but it still worked fine with Linux in the testing.

I'm not really sure, but maybe there's some aspect of Skype which is adaptable to the incoming audio, because the music from the YouTube music video seemed to get a bit better after a minute or so.

Looking at the comments it's also possible that the original asker, Simona, did something like this:

> Thank you again, earthmeLon. I am not sure exactly what happened, but in the end the problem somehow fixed itself: between my last message to you and this one, I played around with my pavucontrol settings and somehow I managed to fix the problem. Unfortunately, I mucked there for such a long time that I don't really know what I did right :|

Two other methods would be:

-[Zoom has built in screen sharing with audio in Linux](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201362643-Sharing-computer-sound-in-a-screen-share). I used this for a meeting in April of 2022, and it worked fine, but I didn't need to keep Zoom so I canceled the subscription.

-Could try running a Windows virtual machine on a Linux host. I haven't tried this, but the thought occurred to me.

Note: There appear to be at least two duplicates of this question:

[share computer sound on skype?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231447/share-computer-sound-on-skype)

[How to share screen in Skype with audio in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285436/how-to-share-screen-in-skype-with-audio-in-ubuntu-20-04)

It says here though on Meta Stack Exchange that one shouldn't copy and paste the same answer to different questions:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions