# How to share screen in Skype with audio in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, skype, pavucontrol

How to share screen in Skype with audio in Ubuntu 20.04? Screen sharing works but system sound cannot be heard from other computer. How to fix it?

Comment: Are you using Snap version or deb version?

Comment: @Kulfy snap....